# Chrome extension failed to load javascript because of protocol-relative URL

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm developing a Chrome extension where I load a javascript file from external domain to which I have no access. This javascript in it's turn loads another javascript with relative protocol method `//exemple.com/javascript.js`. And the problem is: I get an error

> Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED chrome-extension://exemple.com/javascript.js

P.S. My manifest looks like this 
`"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://example.com 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self' https://example.com"`

Comment: Could you please provide more details? Do you mean you are loading first script which also loads another script? What is the path of your first script?

Comment: Or do you just mean the typo `exemple.com <-> example.com`?